# Want to add an object in Realm but object reference is created from builder pattern

Tags: android, realm, builder, android-database

Want to add an object in Realm but object reference is created from Builder pattern. Realm is asking for getter for attributes. Is it possible to add object in Realm without getter but with Builder class ?

Comment: How does builder get in the way of adding getters to your class?

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the [Eliminate @Boilerplate](https://realm.io/news/360andev-ryan-harter-eliminate-boilerplate/) talk, you could create builders for your RealmObjects (please note that AutoValue support isn't in, though, because abstract classes aren't supported).

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    String username;

    String firstname;

    String lastname;

    int age;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

You could create a builder like this:

```
public final class UserBuilder {
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public UserBuilder() {
    }

    public UserBuilder username(String username) {
        this.username = username;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder firstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder lastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder age(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }

    public User build() {
        User user = new User();
        user.username = this.username;
        user.firstName = this.firstName;
        user.lastName = this.lastName;
        user.age = this.age;
        return user;
    }
}
```

This is possible since 0.88.0 and above, because the Realm-Transformer changes all field access to proxy method calls.

**However**, with this setup, I'm not sure how you would reliably modify a managed RealmObject, because to preserve relationships, it's important to use the same managed object (use `findFirst()` and then setters) - considering an unmanaged object is considered a "new" object, and saving it over your previous object with the same primary key invalidates your object links to it.

Answer (score -1):

No, realm uses proxy- method for assigning object fields. You should consider using Data Access objects - abstract interface around your database. Create data model, which will be used by your application and another model (probably with the same fields), ONLY used by Realm. 
It will be more code, but by doing so you will be independent from database implementation. 
You model object should be created by Builder and then accepted by someDao database interface. In implementation of that interface you will convert this object into Realm object.

Comment: Yes, Realm uses proxy methods for assigning object fields, but all field access is converted to proxy method call using the Realm-Transformer.